# "The system cannot find the path specified" error on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, visual-studio-2013, nltk

I'm trying to use nltk with Visual Studio 2013, but everytime I import nltk it gives me the error. I've already installed pythontools and python with nltk. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your solution path contains some illegal character like %. It happened to me.